# Can you explain me VMWare Performance Counters in Windows?

Tags: windows, performance, virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization

I am having a guest Windows Server 2008 R2, i.e. VMWare virtual machine

Can you explain me VM counters vs. non-VM-ones, in the case of  "% Processor Time" (under "VM Processor" section) vs. "% Processor Time" (under "Processor Information" section)
(added in Performance Monitor, aka System Monitor),
which I observe with 1000s per cents and even negative ones?

[image]